# INDEX / MATCH with multiple criteria including a date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to pull prices based on whether the code matches, and if the date is within a certain range.

I want to pull column `H` based on these conditions:

- Columns `A` and `F` match
- Column `G` is between or equal to columns `B` and `C`

I figured an array formula with `INDEX`/`MATCH` would be the best method, but have not been successful so far.

I've been attempting a formula using logic similar to this:

```
{=INDEX(H2:H10, MATCH(1, IF(A2=F2:F10,IF(B2<=G2:G10,IF(C2>=G2:G10,1),0),0),0))}
```

[image: Sample picture]

Comment: will there be duplicate information that fit the criteria? if not then SUMIFS will be easier and more effective.

Comment: Yes there are duplicates unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first then use this array form of INDEX:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$10,MATCH(1,(($F$2:$F$10=A2)*($G$2:$G$10>=B2)*($G$2:$G$10<=C2)),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the matching prices, you can use the `TEXTJOIN()` function:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter the following formula in `D3` and copy-paste/fill down the column:

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(1/(1/(($F$2:$F$10=A2)*($G$2:$G$10>=B2)*($G$2:$G$10<=C2)*($H$2:$H$10))),""))}
```

Note that `TEXTJOIN()` is only available in Excel 2016. In earlier versions of Excel, a poly-fill UDF is required. (See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1331555) for a basic one.)