Lookup value between two dates in excel
I need to find the first value in COLUMN C that has the text yy in COLUMN B. But is also between the start and end date B1 and B2.
I've tried a variety of options based on similar questions but cannot seem to get it working.
Value in yellow (13.48) is what I expect. COL A will always be sorted by date as shown

Using this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1333510/127680
I am able to get most of working using below formula. But it looks for full text - not just the YY part
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,((B:B="apple yy red")*(A:A>=B1)*(A:A<=B2)),0))


A workaround of this issue is this:
I used simple numbers instead of dates, but works with dates too.
=INDEX(C$1:C$13,MIN(IF((A5:A13>=$B$1)*(A5:A13<=$B$2)*(IFERROR(SEARCH("yy",$B$5:$B$13)>0,0)),ROW($A$5:$A$13),"")))

